# Mesh with mirror modifier shaded differently on the other half

Tags: shaders, mirror

Does anyone know on what occasion is mesh with mirror modifier shaded differently on the other half? Normal is fine. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if there is no duplicated object.

Comment: @LeoNas No duplicated object.

Comment: If you want it, you can send the file using this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @LeoNas Thanks.  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=yPRQ8xOP" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/yPRQ8xOP/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that Custom Split Normals are causing the issue.

In the *Data* panel, under *Geometry Data*, click the *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* button to fix it.

Comment: Nice it works! Thanks!